# EF Core tracking immutable value objects

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ef-core-2.0

In my application I follow DDD principles so I have some `ValueObject` like the footer settings

```
public class FooterSettings : ValueObjectBase<FooterSettings>
{
    public bool ShowAddress { get; private set; }
    public bool ShowPageCount { get; private set; }
    public bool ShowAppVersion { get; private set; }

    private FooterSettings() { }

    public FooterSettings (bool showAddress, bool showPageCount, bool showAppVersion)
    {
        this.ShowAddress = showAddress;
        this.ShowPageCount = showPageCount;
        this.ShowAppVersion = showAppVersion ;
    }
}
```

and my DBcontext model creating mapping

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Domain.Page>()
            .OwnsOne(x => x.FooterSettings); 
}
```

Now every time I change the `FooterSettings` and try to set the new value object to the `Page.FooterSettings` I get the following exception

`The instance of entity type 'Page.FooterSettings#FooterSettings' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'PageId:8' is already being tracked. When replacing owned entities modify the properties without changing the instance or detach the previous owned entity entry first.`

Comment: Same issue as [Error When Updating Owned Types #10580](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10580) marked as duplicate of [Allow replacing the dependent side of an identifying FK with a new instance #7340](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7340). According to the Milestone, you could expect it to work in the next EFC 2.1.0 You should either wait or break the principles (use mutable objects)